# DAW Audio Plugin Development for Non-Destructive Operations (e.g. Cut, Fade)

Tags: audio, plugins, add-on, vst

I want to create a plugin for DAWs such as Adobe Audition or Pro Tools, etc. that would do something like this:

1. Download a text file (just into the memory would be enough)
2. Apply the commands in this file (mostly cut and potentially cross-fade operations) to a project file in a non-destructive manner as if the user just would have done it manually
3. Allow the user of the DAW the possibility to keep or remove the individual cuts

Now, I know there are VST, VST3, Audio Unit, etc. But additionally some tools might have their own plugin or add-on functionality. But since this is more a "tool" than an instrument (VSTi) or effect (VSTfx), I'm not sure if these systems are the right way to go.

What would be the recommended way of going about developing such a plugin?

Comment: SO isn’t great for this kind of question. I’d highly recommend the JUCE forums though. If you’re interested in plug-ins for ProTools they’ll have to be AAX and there is a good support network for those https://forum.juce.com/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Will check it out and loop back here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got an [answer](https://forum.juce.com/t/daw-audio-plugin-development-for-non-destructive-operations-e-g-cut-fade/47263) in the Juce forum. I go ahead and quote the summary of the finding:

> So if I understand correctly the way through the plugin architecture doesn’t work for this scenario.
>
> That means such a plugin needs to be developed for each individual DAW, given a supported SDK to build it?
>
> So for example for Adobe Audition we’d need to use the [Adobe Audition SDK](https://www.adobe.io/content/udp/en/apis/creativecloud/audition.html). For Pro Tools [this one](https://developer.avid.com/) or Reaper with [ReaScript](https://www.reaper.fm/sdk/reascript/reascript.php).

Answer (score 1):

Reaper DAW allows such funtionality with [ReaScript](https://www.reaper.fm/sdk/reascript/reascript.php)

There are numerous Reascript examples out there which you can checkout already - [ReaTeam Scripts](https://github.com/ReaTeam/ReaScripts)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, many seem to have their own methods besides the more standardised plugins  (VST*). But what I was wondering is what the right approach is for the specific use case I have. But thanks for the pointer for ReaScript either way!